# extract 'date-related' string from a sentence-python

Tags: python, string, date, datetime, python-datetime

I am new to python, and want to find all 'date-related' words in a sentence, such as date, Monday, Tuesday, last week, next week, tomorrow, yesterday, today, etc.

```
For example:
input: 'Yesterday I went shopping'
return: 'Yesterday'
input: 'I will start working on Tuesday'
return: 'Tuesday'
input: 'My birthday is 1998-12-12'
return: '1998-12-12'
```

I find that python package 'datefinder' can find these words, but it will automatically change these words to standard datetime. However, I only want to extract these words, is there any other method or package that can do this?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: one option is to create `list` with all date-related words and if its in sentence return that. For digits you can do any digits greater 4 return.

Comment: Take a look at the `datefinder` module again. The function has arguments after all. :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how I would do the logic for it, as far as getting the numbers from a string that contains digits as well I'm not sure, I would create and input that would specifically ask for digits then as I did firstSentence.lower() I would then do firstSentence = int(firstSentence) to ensure only ints passed

```
firstSentence = raw_input('Tell me something: ')
firstSentence = firstSentence.lower()
if 'yesterday' in firstSentence:
    #now pass a function that returns date/time
    pass
elif 'tuesday' in firstSentence:
    #now pass a function that returns date/time
    pass
else:
    print 'No day found'
```